# JTree node rename preserve user object

Tags: java, swing, jtree

When a JTree node is edited, the node's user object is lost (set to String). How do I get the original user object? Because I would to like to get the user object's id so as to update the edited name in the database.

I am using TreeModelListener's treeNodesChanged method as shown below.

```
public void treeNodesChanged(TreeModelEvent e) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node;
    node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (e.getTreePath().getLastPathComponent());
    try {
        int index = e.getChildIndices()[0];
        node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (node.getChildAt(index));
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {}        
    System.out.println(node.getUserObject().getClass()); // my user object gone
}
```

So is there any way where I can get the original user object before edit? Any DefaultTreeCellRenderer or DefaultTreeCellEditor methods to override?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement [TreeModel.valueForPathChanged()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html#valueForPathChanged%28javax.swing.tree.TreePath,%20java.lang.Object%29). Or override [DefaultTreeModel.valueForPathChanged()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#valueForPathChanged%28javax.swing.tree.TreePath,%20java.lang.Object%29) if you're using `DefaultTreeModel`. This is where the new user object is set and it gives you the opportunity to get to the original user object.

Comment: Thanks it works. I used [DefaultTreeModel.valueForPathChanged()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#valueForPathChanged%28javax.swing.tree.TreePath,%20java.lang.Object%29). `Object obj = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)path.getLastPathComponent()).getUserObject(); ((MyClass)obj).setName(newValue.toString()); super.valueForPathChanged(path, obj);` Then in treeNodesChanged I am  able to get the user object with changed value.

Comment: Does it mean that I can call the database update in the valueChanged rather than treeNodesChanged?

Comment: @Praveen `DefaultTreeModel` implementation of `valueForPathChanged()` will call `fireTreeNodesChanged` that will end up in `treeNodesChanged` all in all. Just make sure you don't block Swing's `Event Dispatch Thread` with database access. Look into SwingWorker for lengthy tasks.